# File scanner only reading last number in file

Tags: java, file

Here is the code:

```
Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(file);

        while (fileRead.hasNext()) {
            score = (fileRead.nextInt());
        } 

        if (score >= 90) {
            gradeA++; 
            scores++;
        }   else if (score >=80) {
            gradeB++; 
            scores++;
        }   else if (score >= 70) {
            gradeC++; 
            scores++;
        }   else if (score >= 60) {
            gradeD++; 
            scores++;
        }   else if (score >= 50) {
            gradeF++;
            scores++;
        }   else if (score >100 || score <0) {
            uCount++; 
        }
```

I'm supposed to be figuring out the average of scores, while counting how many are in each letter grade. The problem is that it only reads the last number instead of ~80 different numbers.

Comment: `else if (score >100 ...)` this condition will be evaluated in the first case, `if (score >= 90)`

Comment: Actually it reads all the scores. You assign them to the same variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-else logic doesn't get executed until the while loop ends and the entire file has been processed. Meaning, only the last int will be stored into `score`.

Moving the closing bracket of the while loop should fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring your if else condition inside the while loop.

```
Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(file); 
while (fileRead.hasNext()) {
score = (fileRead.nextInt());  
if (score >= 90) { 
gradeA++; 
scores++; 
} 
else if (score >=80) { 
gradeB++; 
scores++; 
} else if (score >= 70) {
 gradeC++; 
scores++; 
} else if (score >= 60) { 
gradeD++; 
scores++; 
} else if (score >= 50) {
 gradeF++; 
scores++; 
} else if (score >100 || score <0) {
 uCount++; 
}
}
```